# Maven: How to consolidate Manifest information from dependencies into one file

Tags: maven, build, maven-2, version, manifest

I have a Mavenized war module which depends on other Mavenized dependencies. Each will come with its own version. However, I wish to consolidate all the version information from each dependency into a single static file, which I will deploy with my webapp to show the version information.

This may be achieved by using multiple Maven plugins (copy resources plugin, or replace plugin). But is there a standard plugin specifically suited to achieve the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) which has a goal [`tree`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) which seemed to the right choice for your problem.
You can define the goal `tree` and use the option [`outputFile`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html#outputFile) to create a stand-alone file which contains the full tree of our project.